# how to not connected list Adapter to layout file not connect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, listadapter, android-studio-3.0

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
List<String> mListData;

public ListAdapter(List<String> mListData) {
    this.mListData = mListData;
}
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType)
{

    View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,viewGroup,false);
    return new myViewHolder(view);
}
```

Comment: `how to not connected list Adapter to layout file not connect` what does it mean?

Comment: please show your code of list adapter completely.